# Stochastic ordering when multiplying pdfs

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, random-variables

Let $X$ and $Y$ be independent random variables with probability density functions $f_X$ and $f_Y$ respectively. Let $X$ first-order stochastically dominate $Y$.

Consider a random variable $W$ whose probability density function is the product of the two pdfs, that is, $f_W(x) = \frac{1}{N}f_X(x) f_Y(x)$, where N is a normalization factor $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f_X(x) f_Y(x)dx$.

I want to prove that $W$ falls "in between" $X$ and $Y$, that is:

1. $X$ first-order stochastically dominate $W$.
2. $W$ first-order stochastically dominates $Y$.

Is this statement true?

Comment: If you define $f_Z(z)=\frac12(f_X(z)+f_Y(z))$, then you can conclude $X \succeq Z\succeq Y$. Also, if $T$ is a random variable whose cdf satisfies $F_T(t)=1-\sqrt{(1-F_X(t))(1-F_Y(t))}$, then  $X \succeq T\succeq Y$.

Answer (score 1):

Take the example

- $X \sim \text{Exp}(1)$ i.e. $f_X(x)=e^{-x}$ for $x\ge 0$
- $Y \sim \text{Exp}(2)$ i.e. $f_Y(x)=2e^{-2x}$ for $x\ge 0$

Then $f_X(x) f_Y(x) = 2e^{-3x}$ for $x\ge 0$ giving $N=\frac23$

so $W \sim \text{Exp}(3)$ i.e. $f_W(x)=3e^{-3x}$ for $x\ge 0$

$W$ does not stochastically dominate $Y$ here; instead $Y$ stochastically dominates $W$

Comment: This answer is exactly what I was looking for! Thanks a lot. Now I wonder if it is possible to prove any restriction on the stochastic ordering. For instance is it possible to find X and Y such that W stochastically dominates both X and W (the opposite of the example provided). Or is such an ordering impossible?

Comment: @user3679030 You could try $-Y$  stochastically dominating $-X$ here and both being stochastically dominated by $-W$

Comment: This is helpful, thanks!